# How do I use a regular expression to match a fixed-length number with a hyphen in the middle?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new to regular expressions and wanted to know how to write a regular expression that does the following:

Validates a string like 123-0123456789.  Only numeric values and a hyphen should be allowed.  Also, verify that there are 3 numeric chars before the hyphen and 10 chars after the hyphen.

Comment: This is a very good regular expressions reference: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 11):

The given answers won't work for strings with more digits (like '012-0123456789876'), so you need:

```
str.match(/^\d{3}-\d{10}$/) != null;
```

or

```
/^\d{3}-\d{10}$/.test(str);
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
^\d{3}-\d{10}$
```

This says:
Accept only 3 digits, then a hyphen, then only 10 digits

Comment: You must anchor your regex unless it matches `...123456-123456789123...`

Answer (score 2):

Sure, this should work:

```
var valid = (str.match(/^\d{3}-\d{10}$/) != null);
```

Example:

```
> s = "102-1919103933";
"102-1919103933"
> var valid = s.match(/\d{3}-\d{10}/) != null;
> valid
true
> s = "28566945";
"28566945"
> var valid = s.match(/\d{3}-\d{10}/) != null;
> valid
false
```

Comment: You must anchor your regex unless it matches `...123456-123456789123...`